# what are Windows Critical updates ? and why they are installing it

Tags: windows, windows-10

I got a warning in windows notification center, that i have to install critical updates , i doont know what is the issue with my computer, but it is asking for critical updates, i searched and found [this](https://windowsmaximizer.com/blog/windows-automatic-update/) post stating that critical updates are to be installed in order to update security. but i donot know if this will work. is there are any threat on not installing updates? i am not a tech person. i have some important data on computer. sorry for bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Critical updates are security updates and are for many computers (millions). The message is not directed at your individual computer except to say updates are pending and need to be done. So just update, restart and carry on. You should be good to go at that point

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft:

If you read Microsoft's definition of "Critical" it means

> " A widely released fix for a specific problem that addresses a critical, non-security->related bug."

but I think they are just as important as Security Updates......

[Source of Information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/824684/description-of-the-standard-terminology-that-is-used-to-describe-micro)